# Change MATLAB Compiler Runtime jvm version

Tags: matlab, jvm, version

I'm wondering how to change the MATLAB Compiler Runtime jvm version? The default is java 1.6. I want to change it to java 1.7. I have set the MATLAB_JAVA environment variable, however it does not work.

Please help me!

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. I tried before, and it seemed to work for a bit, just to cause problems later.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1812J/).

You can also take a look at your

```
[ matlabroot '/bin/' computer('arch') '/java.opts' ]
```

file to look at the configuration passed to the java as well.