# MATLAB: How to get urlread2 to work with HTTPS

Tags: java, matlab, ssl, https, jvm

While trying to scrape data from a website using `urlread2`, I got an error message with the following Java exception: 'Could not generate DH keypair'

In the past, I had used `urlread2` effectively with HTTP.  That fact combined with the Java exception above made it easy to determine that `urlread2` was having problems negotiating the SSL handshake, which begged the question...

How can I get urlread2 to work with HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In researching the problem, I came across this Stack Overflow question:

[Java: Why does SSL handshake give 'Could not generate DH keypair' exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception)

One answer suggested upgrading to the latest JDK (1.8.0_73 as of now.)  I did that, but my code still didn't work.  It occurred to me that MATLAB might have a default Java Virtual Machine (JVM) setting that might need to be changed, so I looked for instructions on how to do that.

I found such instructions here: [Change MATLAB Compiler Runtime jvm version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428520/change-matlab-compiler-runtime-jvm-version)

And here: [Matlab Central: How do I change the Java Virtual Machine?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103056-how-do-i-change-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm-that-matlab-is-using-for-mac-os)

After upgrading to the latest JDK and changing the default JVM settings for MATLAB, `urlread2` now works with HTTPS.

Comment: I recommend not to change the jvm. Matlab itself is implemented to a large part in Java and only tested with the jvm it ships.

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, I've seen that comment elsewhere, but I figured that I could change it back after scraping the website.  But thanks for adding that fact: I had meant to include it in the original question/answer.